# Double integral of branch function when integrating with respect to the condition

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In my probability class I have resorted to calculating a seemingly difficult integral for finding the expectation of a conditional expectation (law of total expectation) the function is:

$$ F(\alpha, f) = \begin{cases}
  2  & \text{if } |f| \leq \alpha \\
  0 & \text{if } |f| > \alpha
 \end{cases} $$

I need to find the integral

$$ \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1} F(\alpha, f) \,d\alpha $$

I have never met this sort of integral before where we integral w.r.t the condition defining variable, so I am asking here in the hopes of learning how to compute this. I thank all helpers.

Comment: Are the two $f$s in "$f(\alpha,f)$" supposed to be two different things? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes sorry fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|f|\le\frac12$ then
$$\int_{\frac12}^1F(\alpha,f)d\alpha=\int_{\frac12}^12d\alpha=1$$
If $\frac12<|f|\le1$ then
$$\int_{\frac12}^1F(\alpha,f)d\alpha=\int_{|f|}^12d\alpha=2\left(1-|f|\right)$$
If $|f|>1$ then
$$\int_{\frac12}^1F(\alpha,f)d\alpha=\int_{\frac12}^10d\alpha=0$$
Thus
$$\int_{\frac12}^1F(\alpha,f)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}1&\text{if }|f|\le\frac12\\
2\left(1-|f|\right)&\text{if }\frac12<|f|<1\\
0&\text{if }|f|>1\end{array}\right.$$
That is unless there is more meaning to the symbol $f$ than is contained in the original question.